Advantage of GLMs over transformation models
According to the book I am currently reading, we should prefer GLMs over a simple transformation model (e.g. $\log(y) = x_i^T \beta + u_i$ ) The argument is derived by Jensen's inequality:
$$
E(\log(\text{y}) \mid x) \leq \log E(\text{y} \mid x)
$$
$$
\exp\{E(\log(\text{y}) \mid x)\} \leq E(\text{y} \mid x)
$$
I am not sure whether I really understand the punchline of the inequality.
My thoughts so far:
What we are really interested in, is typically $E(y | x)$. That's probably why we take the $\exp()$ to get to the second inequality. But the left hand side is only feasible if GLM is applied, whereas I run into trouble with the transformed model. This is probably referring to the well-known problem, that I cannot simply take the $\exp()$, when I derived the result with the transformation model, right? And consequently, if I did regression with GLM I can be sure, that my result is either equal or below the true expectation?
Any input is welcome!

You don't transform the response with a GLM.

can you provide name of the book and exact quote

Thanks for pointing out, I corrected the last sentence.

Link functions (in GLM) and transformations are not the same, see this video explanation.

An implicit assumption in this argument is that you do want to model the conditional expectation of $Y.$  However, the spirit of transformations is that the transformed variable may be of more direct interest (as it often is in the physical sciences: think of activities or pH, which are actually logarithms of concentrations), in which case it is the GLM that produces biased results!

“According to the book I am currently reading, we should prefer GLMs over a simple transformation model" This is very unclear. What is the situation? Related is maybe Why would you perform transformations over polynomial regression?. Transformations can be useful; Possibly not as alternative to glm, but on their own they have their own uses.

The punchline is that the GLM is directly estimating E(y|x), whereas the transformed model is estimating E(ln(y)|x).
You don't have a way of generating a prediction of E(y|x) from E(ln(y)|x): the inequality is showing that just taking the exponential is biased (underestimating).
Note: there are adjustments to approximately undo the bias (I forget the name), but that doesn't affect the argument.
edit 1 adjustment: assume the residuals of the log transformed probability are iid normally distributed; then the expectation of a log normal variable with parameters $(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is $\exp(\mu+1/2 \sigma^2)$. So you can estimate the original variable as $\exp(\text{prediction of log transformed} + 1/2 \ \text{mean squared error of log_transformed})$

Ah great, thanks! Meaning that I have the GLM on the right hand side which is exactly modeling the expectation? Whereas I am only getting a rough idea applying the exp() to the transformation model on the left hand side?

exactly (and was the meaning of Glen_b's comment to your question)

The allusion may be to smearing as in Naihua Duan's paper from 1983 https://www.jstor.org/stable/2288126

@NickCox, thank you! yes that's what i was searching for

Can you provide more details to what the book is exactly referring to?
I think the important distinction between transformation models and GLMs is that for transformation models, your goal is to apply a transformation such that the data becomes approximately normal (this is when OLS tends to work well). See also the following Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform) which states

It is a data transformation technique used to stabilize variance, make the data more normal distribution-like, improve the validity of measures of association (such as the Pearson correlation between variables), and for other data stabilization procedures.

However, just applying such transformations will not always give you data that looks approximately normal. Think about binary data, for which such transformations are not available. A GLM would be more appropriate in this case as it assumes a different distribution for $Y|X$ and then models $E[Y|X]$ following that distribution. In particular, for binary data you would assume that the dependent is Bernoulli distributed. However, the GLM is more general and you could also consider other distributions such as Poisson, Binomial, Exponential, etc. (see the table on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model).
So, overall I do not think one model is necessarily better than the other. It really depends on the data.

As in your penultimate paragraph, it is the distribution of the outcome conditional on the predictors that is crucial. There is a widespread overemphasis on the marginal distribution of the outcome.

@NickCox yes, I completely agree. I could have been more precise there. Thank you.
